# nokogiri xml is not parsed the way I want

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to print below xml which is simplified for the question here.
I have hard time printing it the way I want.
How to print the correct output below?

```
# xml
<Info>
  <Server NAME="host1">
    <From_Version>
      <Transition INDEX="1" VALUE="1234"/>
    </From_Version>
    <state>
      <Transition INDEX="1" DATE="2016-06-14"/>
      <Transition INDEX="2" DATE="2016-06-15"/>
    </state>
  </Server>
  <Server NAME="host2">
    <From_Version>
      <Transition INDEX="1" VALUE="1234"/>
    </From_Version>
    <state>
      <Transition INDEX="1" DATE="2016-07-14"/>
      <Transition INDEX="2" DATE="2016-07-15"/>
    </state>
  </Server>
</Info>

# code
require 'nokogiri'

xml = File.open( "d:/temp/test.xml" )
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

doc.xpath("//Server").each do |row|
  #puts row
  puts row["NAME"]
  #puts s

  row.xpath("//state//Transition").each do |idx|
    puts "#{idx['INDEX']} #{idx['DATE']}"
  end
end

# current output
host1
1 2016-06-14
2 2016-06-15
1 2016-07-14
2 2016-07-15
host2
1 2016-06-14
2 2016-06-15
1 2016-07-14
2 2016-07-15

# correct output
host1
1 2016-06-14
2 2016-06-15
host2
1 2016-07-14
2 2016-07-15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.//` instead of `//`.

> - //para selects all the para descendants of the root document node and thus selects all para elements in the same document as the context node
> - .//para selects the para element descendants of the context node

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#abbrev

---

```
doc.xpath("//Server").each do |row|
  #puts row
  puts row["NAME"]

  row.xpath(".//state//Transition").each do |idx|
    puts "#{idx['INDEX']} #{idx['DATE']}"
  end
end

# output
# host1
# 1 2016-06-14
# 2 2016-06-15
# host2
# 1 2016-07-14
# 2 2016-07-15
```